# Get 3 consecutive tails in coin flipping?

Tags: probability

I Have been trying for so Many days to find the solution of this problem

"The number of ways we can get atleast 3 consecutive tails if we toss the coin 'n' number of times?"

Can anyone help me here?

Answer (score 3):

Count the number of ways to *not* get 3 consecutive tails, denote this number $a_n$.
For $n\ge 3$, such a way will have a heads among the last three rounds, i.e., will end in either $H$ or $HT$ or $HTT$. 
Hence a way of length $n$ is either a way of length $n-1$ followed by $H$, a way of length $n-2$ followed by $HT$, or a way of length $n-3$ followed by $HTT$. Deduce that $$a_n=a_{n-1}+a_{n-2}+a_{n-3}$$
and use this recursion to express $a_n$. Subtract the result from $2^n$ to answer the original question.